# Can't see flash content in html Django

Tags: javascript, html, django, flash

First of all sorry about my english, I will try to explain it the best way I can.

I'm new working with Django. I have a html page with flash content named map.html, and I like to include it into another page named soporte.html (which extends base.html page) through {% include %} tag. If I open map.html directly without django, in firefox for example, I can see the flash content, but if I open the whole project using django (in firefox too) and I go to the page where is suposed to be the map I can't see anything.

What am I doing wrong??

Here is the code:

map.html

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="swfobject.js"></script>
<div id="flashcontent">
    <strong>You need to upgrade your Flash Player</strong>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    // <![CDATA[        
    var so = new SWFObject("ammap.swf", "ammap", "900", "600", "8", "#FFFFFF");
    so.addVariable("path", "ammap/");
    so.addVariable("settings_file", escape("ammap_settings.xml"));                  
    so.addVariable("data_file", escape("ammap_data.xml"));      
    so.write("flashcontent");
    // ]]>
</script>
```

soporte.html

```
    {% extends "base.html" %}
    {% load i18n %}
    {% block contenido %}
    {% include "map.html" %}
    {% endblock %}
```

base.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/common.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/swfobject.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
    {% load i18n %}
    {% block contenido %}{% endblock %}
    </body>
    </html>
```

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: And what's the result page source?

Answer (score 1):

At a guess, you don't have anything serving your static Javascript or Flash files. See [the static files documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/howto/static-files/).